# How to assign maven (?) coordinates to my Gradle project?

Tags: java, maven, gradle

I would like to use one of my projects (called `filterwidget`) from within another projects with

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mycompany</groupId>
        <artifactId>filterwidget</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

with Maven or by

```
    compile('mycompany:filterwidget:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT')
```

with Gradle.

I think `mycompany:filterwidget:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT` is called "Maven coordinates" of my project, right?

So, how assign maven coordinates to my Gradle project?

I have

```
jar {
    baseName = 'filterwidget'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

is this enough? Where is group id set?

In other words, what is `Gradle` equivalent for

```
<project ...>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>filterwidget</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

**UPDATE**

Answer (score 2):

You would specify the project properties like this:

```
group 'mycompany'
version '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
```

Maven's `artifactId` is the project name inside of Gradle and is derived from your project's directory name. So in your example, you have to put your project into a directory called `filterwidget`.

You do specify these properties on the top level of your `build.gradle` file, the `jar` properties you have used are intended for different things: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html

Comment: I set `project.version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'` and `project.group   = 'mycompany'` according to here https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html#sub:installing_to_the_local_repository and it worked. Why is it differ from your code and what is the difference?

Comment: What you've done is configure your gradle to allow for generation of a Maven POM. I don't if that's waht you're trying to achieve? I assume you simply wanted to configure your Gradle to have the same depdency URL as your Maven project and I'd say, than my proposed aproach is the "correct" way to do it.

But whatever works for your use case...